# Are Django model forms are required by default and how to set required to false for whole form?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

**models.py:**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    site = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.DecimalField(default=10.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_venue = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

**forms.py**

```
class VenueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'city',
            'address',
            'phone',
            'email',
            'site',
            'facebook',
            'instagram',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VenueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].label = "Име"
        self.fields['content'].label = 'Описание'
        self.fields['city'].label = 'Град'
        self.fields['address'].label = 'Адрес'
        self.fields['phone'].label = 'Телефон'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'E-mail'
        self.fields['site'].label = 'Сайт'
```

**html render:**

```
<form method="post" id="dialog_addVenue_part" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in postForm.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <div class="errorcode{{field.html_name}}">
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;">

    </div>
    <div class="utf_addVenue_form">
        <button type="submit" value="Изпрати">Изпрати</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Part of HTML with required fields:**

```
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="errorcodesite">

        </div>
        <label for="id_site">Сайт:</label> <input type="text" name="site" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_site">

</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <div class="errorcodefacebook">

    </div>
    <label for="id_facebook">Facebook:</label> <input type="text" name="facebook" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_facebook">

</div>
```

I have not indicated anywhere that form should have "required" to all fields but they comes with it. So, Are Django model forms are required by default and how to set required to false for whole form?

Comment: In general you need to consider two arguments when constructing a model. Blank and null parameter. Field with `blank=True` means it won't be required in the form, however, if you do not provide it and don't have a default set, saving will crash, because the model field cannot be null. Also, it is better to use `null=True` than `default=''` and instead of adding labels to form fields, add `verbose_name` to model fields. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/](Docs).

Comment: @Borut Thanks for the info.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/) link again.

Comment: But labels are easy for styling, is the same with `verbose_name` ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with styling. In my experience it's the same. But it's your choice. You don' t have to use it if you don't want to. I prefer it, because form code looks cleaner this way. I very rarely had to override `verbose_name` with label in ModelForms.

Answer (score 1):

Add `blank=True` to the fields you don't need to be required.

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    . . .
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    . . .
```

Comment: Can you provide example ?